# Clear cell content based on number of tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a VBA code for deleting a cell content based on the number of tabs it contains. For example: in column K, delete cell content if it contains  5 tabs and below- 101-6 or 101- will be deleted but 101-61 won't be deleted.

Comment: Do you mean "characters" rather than "tabs"?  I wouldn't generally use VBA for this - you can use built-in Excel functionality to do this perfectly well.  Formulae or filters will work.

Comment: You're right, Characters! The problem with filtering is that I have thousands of rows so filtering is quite messy and that is why I want to eliminate all the cells with less than 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop through range
    For i = 6 To myLastRow
        If mid(Cells(i, "J").Value ,instr(Cells(i, "J").Value ,"-"),) <=5  Then Range(Cells(i, "O"), Cells(i, "Y")).ClearContents
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thank you! Just so I understand- How do you refer to a specific column in this code?

Comment: If mid(Cells(i, "PUT YOUR CELL COLUMN HERE").Value ,instr(Cells(i, "PUT YOUR CELL COLUMN HERE").Value ,"-"),) <=5  Then Range(Cells(i, "PUT YOUR CELL COLUMN HERE"), Cells(i, "PUT YOUR CELL COLUMN HERE")).ClearContents